# Watch for user key press in Custom TextView

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android, and I want to do this. Listen for `.` in my textview.

Currently I have my own `View` class which implements `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` for highlighting (in colors) the text when user types, based on the requirement.

The reason for using a custom view is, I want the view to update its color based on the user input (i.e text).

So my layout xml looks like this:

```
<mypackage.SyntaxEditor
        android:id="@+id/myText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLength="99999999"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        >
    </mypackage.SyntaxEditor>
```

And in my activity class I have the following code:

```
SyntaxEditor text = v.findViewById(R.id.myText) 

//and few adapters
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, methods);
text.setAdapter(adapter)
text.setThreshold(2)
```

Now I have an requirement like, when ever user press `.` I need to do update the `adapter` from `SyantaxEditor`.

Now I have this problem, in `SyntaxEditor`, I wish to change the array of values in the `adapter`, is that possible to do so? Am I following the right approach for the problem?

Or my class design is wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A little bit more info would help.Why are you using a custom text view?And also check out Textwatcher class https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html
and when you say change the adapter do you mean the array for your  adapter neds to change?

Comment: @Shade23: Ya change the array of adapter. Sorry was a typo

Comment: then combine textwatcher https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html and a custom adapter which will modify the dataset,then call notifydatasetchaned whenever needed.
If you need cod elet me know..will add some

Comment: @Shade23: Ya. My basic doubt here is, I want to modifiy the dataset. For that I need to create an`ArrayAdapter` again, which requires activity context, how will I get that? Can you give me an small example in a code snippet?

Comment: :do you need a different answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an existing arrayadapter,you can merely modify the existing dataset.
first set the implicit notifydatasetchanged to [false](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#setNotifyOnChange%28boolean%29)

```
adapter.setNotifyOnChange(false);
```

then [remove](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#clear%28%29) the existing elements in your array and [add](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20T%3E%29) the new elements

```
adapter.clear()
adapter.addAll(newMethods);
```

You are setting the implicit notification to false because you dont want the view to update both times (when you clear and add elements to the list).

You dont have to worry about context here.